# Deploy idea web module on jetty

Tags: intellij-idea, webserver, jetty, jetty-9, servlet-container

I deleted the content of the project's artifacts folder and now the server throws a configuration error:

> deployment source 'Hello World IDEA JETTY:war exploded2' is not valid

How can I redeploy the web server module onto the server?

Comment: I would expect that one of the right click options of the module to offer deployment onto the server, but I can't find such an option nor another.